# Mongodb in node js aggregation pipeline postman sending request infinitely

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation

The following is a aggregation pipeline in nodejs where I am trying to get a json response via a get request e.g( http://localhost:4000/api/mySite/reviewsFromGame/Desolate)

the json response will contain all reviews for that game.

this is my route:

```
   router.get('/reviewsFromGame/:id',getGameNameReview)
```

When I tested this pipeline in mongodb compass it works perfectly. But when I try to implement it with a get request via postman it is stuck at sending request indefinitely with no errors what so ever

The code below is the async function for the get request which includes the NodeJS aggregation pipeline that I am trying to get working. and I have no idea what is wrong

```
const getGameNameReview = async (req, res) => {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/project');
  const db = client.db('project');
  const { id } = req.params;
  try {
    const game = await db.collection('game').findOne(
      { app_name: id },
      { projection: { _id: 0, app_id: 1 } }
    );
    if (game) {
      console.log(game.app_id)
      const reviews = await db.collection('game_review').aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            app_id: game.app_id
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "review",
            localField: "review_id",
            foreignField: "review_id",
            as: "review"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: '$review'
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "author",
            localField: "review.review_id",
            foreignField: "review_id",
            as: "author"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: '$author'
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            review_id: "$review.review_id",
            review: "$review.review",
            recommended: "$review.recommended",
            votes_helpful: "$review.votes_helpful",
            votes_funny: "$review.votes_funny",
            app_id: game.app_id,
            app_name: id,
            author_steamid: "$author.author_steamid"
          }
        }
      ]).toArray();
      res.json(reviews); client.close();
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ message: "Game not found" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
}
```

Comment: What has your posted code todo with postman? If this is a http problem where is the http part?  Complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)